# CSS3 Box-shadow not working

Tags: doctype, css, insets

So, I'm having trouble with this code:

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
font-family: Arial;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px rbga(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 10px rbga(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            inset 0 10px 20px rbga(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}
```

In Notepad++ box-shadow does not grey out. Meaning it does not work? 
Is this problem because of the fact that I use a: 
< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
As doctype?

Comment: Are you using some sort of browser preview plugin for Notepad++? Notepad++ itself is a text editor, not a browser.

Comment: @BoltClock She means that syntax is not highlighted

Comment: @jesse Update your notepad++, properties are new, so either they have updated, or it might take a while, but if syntax is not highlighted in your notepad doesn't mean it's wrong, test in on your browser

Comment: @Mr. Alien: No I'm pretty sure that's not what OP meant...

Comment: @Mr.Alien First: I'm not a female. Second: The browser also does not apply the box-shadows.

Comment: @JesseDijkstra Am sorry ;) and read Bolt's answer

Comment: A well, it seems that after changing the rbga's to rgba's it finally works! Thanks for the help all.

Comment: @BoltClock You were right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All but one of your `rgba()`s in your `box-shadow` are misspelled as `rbga()`.